# Firefox incorrectly displays background-image where the height of a div is set to a large number

Tags: css, firefox, background

I found that on a div where the height is set to a large number and a background-image is set, Firefox doesn't show it correctly. It only shows part of background, not 100%. I am using Firefox 12.0 on Windows 7.

You can see this here: http://jsbin.com/firefox-bg-bug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Firefox Background Bug</title>
<style>
  body{
    background-color: #ccc; 
    padding: 10px;
  }
  div{
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAABCAIAAACnuZzqAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAZSURBVHjaYmQQ+v//HSPDKCAEGIX+AwQYAH23BBPJF5FHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    height: 53200px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Scroll to the bottom of page to see the bug. **Firefox Only**

I would like to know if this is really a browser bug and if it is, whether it should be reported on Bugzilla?

**Update:** [image: screenshot]

Comment: I see no difference between Firefox (v11 on ubuntu) and Windows.

Comment: I saw your screenshot. This just look like a (platform dependent) bug. Knowing if it has yet been reported is another problem...

Comment: @dystroy apropos, are you using Windows 7?

Comment: @B7 sorry. I cropped a part. I see no difference (no problem) between Firefox (v11 on ubuntu) and Chrome (ubuntu & Windows). The background doesn't go to the bottom of the page on Firefox on Windows 7. So this might be a bug specific to FF/Windows.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug on my Macbook with Firefox 11 and Firefox 12.

Comment: @dystroy I also tested on Windows XP using Virtual PC — problem persists too. Apropos, try to increase div height.

Comment: For your real problem : I'm sure you don't plan to display a real image with an height of 50000px. Can't you use repeat-y ? If you really need a 50 000 px high image with no repetition, you probably must look for another solution (like canvas). This doesn't mean your question is invalid or uninteresting.

Comment: @dystroy The background image have height 1px and at this moment `repeat` is used. So, Firefox stop repeating image if height is greater that 33000px.

Comment: Firefox 12 - Windows 7 - Cannot reproduce the "bug". It all looks fine.

Comment: reproduced on FF 11, Win XP. seems it's related to scrolling and/or heavy rendering of the base64 image.

Comment: @EliranMalka Initially, the bug was reproduced using the URL to the image. Then, to simplify the code, I used base64. Thus, base64 has no fault.